# Warn when migrating a question to a site the poster may have re-asked on

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-tools

This has happened to me a few times now: Find closed off topic question, maybe a couple hours old, with "belongs on X.stack exchange.com". Well, the question is fine, just off topic, so let's migr--oh, they already asked it on X.stackexchange.com.

It'd be cool if the migration dialog could show some warning that says "hey, they asked a question on the site you're migrating to! Continue? (preview of question)" so mods wouldn't have to manually check other sites for reposted questions/mods on the receiving site don't have to merge/delete duplicates.

Comment: Ideally the there is only one copy of the question on the network with one set of answers... the presence or absence of answers on question is likely a major determinant in what should be done.

Comment: @MichaelT Sometimes a question can legitimately be asked of two sites (e.g. IT Security for theory, Server Fault for practical implementation) - I'll concede that questions that require that kind of dual-input are pretty rare though.

Comment: Isn't merging duplicates beneficial in the long run if a question has already been asked on two sites? It means the answers aren't divided up in two places.

Comment: @MartinSmith that implies that it got answers on each site rather than closed on one site.  Migrating an answerless closed question is of questionable value.

Comment: @MichaelT - Yes, I agree, if it never got any answers on the original site and has been cross posted already on another site it shouldn't get migrated there too.

Answer (score 6):

Most questions that are asked on the wrong site *shouldn't be migrated anyway.*   The question that is well-written, adequately researched and clearly answerable, but just happens to be posted to the wrong site, is a rare bird indeed.

Rather than flagging down mods to get questions migrated, most of the time we should be closing these questions and pointing the user to the correct site, while also advising them that they should read the Help Center articles on the target site and make some effort to improve their question before reposting.

Comment: This seems to be an argument against migration in general rather than the specific point in the question.

Comment: @MartinSmith: True, but if we made the OP fix the problem himself instead of placing so much emphasis on moderator migration, we probably wouldn't need the proposed tool at all.